# python iterate over the two lists while comparing items

Tags: python, list

i have two lists eg `x = [1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7] y = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`, i want to iterate over the two lists while comparing items. For those that match, i would like to call some function and remove them from the lists, in this example i should end up with x= [1,2] and y = [8,9,10]. Sets will not work for this problem because of my type of data and the comparison operator.

```
for i in x:
  for j in y:
    if i ==j:
       callsomefunction(i,j)
       remove i, j from x and y respectively
```

Comment: Your examples were in sorted order. Are your actual data in sorted order?

Comment: Are the data sortable? Why isn't your data hashable? How big are `x` and `y`?

Comment: You mentioned you can't use `set()` because of your comparison operator. I'm curious as to what that would be. Also, would that stop you from doing `if i in y` instead of the inner loop?

Comment: Should the combination `callsomefunction(i, j)` be called exactly once, no matter how many times `i` and `j` are found? If not, what is the rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** After discovering the person asking the question simply didn't know about `__hash__` I provided this information in a comment:

> To use sets, implement `__hash__`. So if `obj1 == obj2` when `obj1.a == obj2.a and ob1.b == obj2.b`, `__hash__` should be `return hash((self.a, self.b))` and your sets will work as expected.

That solved their problem, and they switched to using sets.

The rest of this answer is now obsolete, but it's still correct (but horribly inefficient) so I'll leave it here.

---

This code does what you want. At the end, `newx` and `newy` are the non-overlapping items of `x` and `y` specifically.

```
x = [1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7]
y = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
# you can leave out bad and just compare against
# x at the end if memory is more important than speed
newx, bad, newy = [], [], []
for i in x:
    if i in y:
        callsomefunction(i)
        bad.append(i)
    else:
        newx.append(i)

for i in y:
    if i not in bad:
        newy.append(i)

print newx
print newy
```

However, I know without even seeing your code that this is the wrong way to do this. You can certainly do it with sets, but if you don't want to, that's up to you.

Comment: The problem with sets is my data sets (objects) so the comparision operation is defined to compare specific attributes of the objects. Let me work with this solution.Thanks

Comment: @user739807, Do you mean "I defined `__cmp__` but not `__hash__`"? If so, you might want to define `__hash__`. That could turn this quadratic code into linear code. (Additionally, if you're defining `__cmp__`, you probably want to define `__eq__` instead.)

Answer (score 3):

**Ok, discard my post, I hadn't seen the point where you mentionned that sets wouldn't work.**

Nevertheless, if you're OK with a little work, you might want to use classes so that operators *do work* as they are expected to.

I think the most "pythonistic" way of doing this is to use sets.
You could then do :

```
x = set([1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7])
y = set([3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
for item in x.intersection(y): #y.intersection(x) is fine too.
    my_function(item) #You could use my_function(item, item) if that's what your function requires
    x.remove(item)
    y.remove(item)
```

I think that sets are also more efficient than lists for this kind of work when it comes down to performance (though this might not be your top priority).

On a sidenote, you could also use:

```
x,y = x.difference(y), y.difference(x)
```

This effectively removes items that are in x and y from x and y.

Comment: He's now using sets, it just turned out he didn't know about `__hash__` so he thought it wouldn't work for his objects.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for i in x:
    if i in y:
        callsomefunction(i)
        x.remove(i)
        y.remove(i)
```

EDIT: updated answer

Comment: zip will not work because the lenght of both lists is not the same. and we i also have duplicates

Comment: Did you run this code? This does not produce the output requested by OP.

Comment: `zip()` produces different results for the nested for loop used by OP. `itertools.product()` would be more suitable, if not for the `remove(..)` requirements.

Comment: This actually works, but when x or y has repeating items it only removes one occurancy.

Answer (score -1):

how about this:

```
import itertools
x = [1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7] 
y = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
output = map(somefunction, itertools.product(x,y))
```

Comment: `itertools.product()` gives the correct iteration order, but things may get hairy once you start deleting entries from the list while iterating.